# How to Change a Prefabs Tag Based on Game Score in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would I change an instantiated prefab tag based on the score.

For example, I have prefabs being spawned and sent towards the player to collect, and some to avoid.

When the player gets a high enough score, the objects they are meant to avoid can now also be collected.

I am attempting to achieve this through tags in unity.

When the player reaches lets say a score of 10, the object that would normally kill them will have its tag changed so that it will no longer hurt the player and instead also be collected.

I am struggling to figure out how to get the prefab to recognize the current score, and then change its tag accordingly.

Here is the script I am using to track the score.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager instance;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;
   
    int score = 0;
    int highScore = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0);
        scoreText.text = score.ToString() + "POINTS";
        highScoreText.text = "HIGHSCORE: " + highScore.ToString();
    }

   public void AddPoint()
    {
        score += 1;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString() + "POINTS";
        
        if(highScore < score)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", score);
        }
        
    }
}
```

I was thinking of adding something like this to the Score Manager and then adding this script to the prefab. But this was not the answer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager instance;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;
   
    int score = 0;
    int highScore = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore", 0);
        scoreText.text = score.ToString() + "POINTS";
        highScoreText.text = "HIGHSCORE: " + highScore.ToString();
    }

   public void AddPoint()
    {
        score += 1;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString() + "POINTS";
        
        if(highScore < score)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", score);
        }
        
    }

     public void EditTag()
    {
        if (score >= 10)
        {
            gameObject.tag = "Destructable";
        }
    }
}
```

and for the prefab

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EditTag : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        ScoreManager.instance.EditTag();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Where do you spawn the prefabs? Also, your `ScoreManager.EditTag()` function changes its own tag.

Comment: a prefab is a potential object, not a living one  code is not running on it - you need to change the tag on instantiation..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. in your collectables prefab make a new public int call it whatever
   you want in my case I'm gonna name it reqScore . (reqScore is the required score to make the object collectable)
2. in the inspector give it a value and make sure to apply  the
   changes to the prefab(s).

finally in your prefab script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class EditTag : MonoBehaviour
{

  public int reqScore = 100;
  public int currentScore;


    void Update()
    {
       currentScore = ScoreManager.instance.score;

       if(currentScore >= reqScore ){

        gameObject.tag = "Destructable";

      }
        
    }
}
```

make sure to assign the EditTag Script to your prefab

you can give reqScore any value you want in the inspector for different prefabs
we don't need the EditTag function you may remove it from this ScoreManager  script

```
 public void EditTag()
    {
        if (score >= 10)
        {
            gameObject.tag = "Destructable";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, will update this tomorrow I need get some sleep. Much appreciated!

Comment: yup that worked